# How to edit the assets in the jar version file in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to edit the assets, like the textures of the blocks, in the Minecraft .jar file. For example, I want to change the textures of bottles without using a texture pack, and directly change what Minecraft thinks the default is.

The process I've tried so far is:

- turn version.jar, in this case 1.10.jar into a .zip file
- unzip it into a folder, now just a folder called 1.10
- navigate to 1.10/assets/minecraft/textures/items/bottle.png
- edit that texture
- compress the folder back into a .zip file
- change it to a .jar file
- replace the original version.jar with mine

But when I try to launch it, Minecraft refuses to launch it. Why, and how can I edit Minecraft correctly?

Comment: .jar files are signed and made executable through a complicated process, they're not just renamed .zip files. You could try replacing the file without unpacking and repacking by using the command line version of 7zip, I did that to an Android app once and it worked. In the worst case you would have to decompile and recompile the entire game. But the more important question is: **WHY** do you not want to use resource packs?

Comment: @FabianRöling because I think it would be silly to have a whole resourse pack just to change the look of one block. Also, there are other assets I might want to change that a resource pack can't.

Comment: Which resources? And no, having a resource pack for one file is much more normal than what you're attempting. I have a resource pack that just replaces one texture, it's 2728 Bytes big. I also have one that changes only redstone dust in a certain configuration, it's 4929 Bytes big. I made two resource packs myself recently that only disable a bunch of subtitles, they are 27109 and 27265 Bytes big. There's not really any downside to this, except if you have hundreds of those tiny resource packs that clutter the resource pack menu in the game.

Comment: @FabianRöling the loot tables. I think name tags and lily pads are junk and water bottles and leather are treasure.

Comment: Loot tables are part of data packs as well.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to delete the folder called META-INF otherwise Minecraft will detect that its textures have have been modified and crash.